# Updating hive table with sqoop from mysql table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, data-ingestion

I have already a hive table called roles. I need to update this table with info coming up from mysql. So, I have used this script think that it will add and update new data on my hive table:`

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://nn01.itversity.com/retail_export --username retail_dba --password itversity \ --table roles --split-by id_emp --check-column id_emp --last-value 5 --incremental append \ --target-dir /user/ingenieroandresangel/hive/roles --hive-import --hive-database poc --hive-table roles
```

Unfortunately, that only insert the new data but I can't update the record that already exits. before you ask a couple of statements:

- the table doesn't have a PK
- if i dont specify --last-value  as a parameter I will get duplicated records for those who already exist.

How could I figure it out without applying a truncate table or recreate the table using a PK? exist the way?

thanks guys.

Comment: As you already mention you have to follow the truncate process

Comment: there's not other way?? I afraid not cuz hive dont support the ACID tables schema isn't it. well i just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not operate update queries. 
You have to drop/truncate old table and reload again.